# iOS event for continuous touch

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, touch

I'm writing an iOS app and I can't seem to figure out how to do a continuous touch event. I tried using the "touchesBegan" and "touchesEnd" functions but those aren't for continuous touching.

So basically what I have right now is as follows:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if([touch view] == [self viewWithTag:kTag])
    {
        CGFloat yOffset = contentView.contentOffset.y;
        yOffset ++;
        [contentView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, yOffset)];
    }
}
```

However I want the content offset to continue shifting indefinitely as long as my finger is touching the given view. Right now it stops after one iteration.

Comment: What are you looking for? If you get a touchesBegan then it is continuous until you receive the touchesEnded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your updated question it appears you need to setup a repeating timer in `touchesBegan`. Each time the timer fires, update the offset. Cancel the timer in the `touchesEnded` and `touchesCanceled` methods.

Comment: I've never heard of a repeating timer in iOS before. Can you elaborate? How would I go about implementing one?

Comment: See the docs for `NSTimer`. There are parameters for setting up a repeat when you create the timer.

Answer (score 3):

Are you searching for the `touchesMoved` method? There is such a method that you can use it.

**UPDATE**:

Maddy's solution should work with touches.

Alternatively, you might want to take a look at the following control event method:

`- (BOOL)continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

Comment: The OP does not want the `touchesMoved` method. The idea is the user simply holds their finger down in the screen and the view moves while the finger stays in touch. No movement of the finger required.

Comment: Thanks Maddy. I've already agreed that my answer sounds more of a comment, which was essentially trying to know the requirements. I had just 1 reputation hence couldn't make a comment. Having said that, we can specify a duration in Long Press gesture Recognizer and make use of it. Updated my answer.

Comment: A long press gesture won't work either. That only sends an event after the long press duration has been reached, then as the finger moves, then when the finger is lifted. The OP wants a set of events the entire time the finger sits in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Maddy for the tips.  I got a repeating action while touching working with the information about NSTimer.

I did have it doing a single action each time the screen is tapped:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[rocket.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(0,200)];
}
```

But that would only trigger with each tap.  I wanted it to keep applying force while the screen is touched.

Add a timer to the class:

```
@interface TPMyScene ()
@property (nonatomic, retain, readwrite) NSTimer * touchTimer;
@end
```

Move my action to a method:

```
-(void)boost {
    NSLog(@"Boosting");
    [rocket.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(0,200)];
}
```

Trigger the timer at touchesBegan:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // First we need to trigger a boost in case the screen was just touched.
    [rocket boost];

    //set a timer to keep boosting if the touch continues.  
    //Also check there isn't already a timer running for this.
    if (!self.touchTimer.isValid) {
        self.touchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:rocket selector:@selector(boost) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}
```

Cancel the timer when touching ends either by end or cancel:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.touchTimer invalidate];
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.touchTimer invalidate];
}
```

Comment: My first touchesBegan with just the timer had two bugs once I started testing...  
1. The timer only fired after .1 seconds, so a touch/tap of less than that was cancelled before anything ran.
2. multitouch: second touch would create a new timer and lose the link to the original.  The invalidate would only stop the new one and the old one kept firing forever!